Print 2 pages per sheet of a document generated with Google App Script
I made a Script that searches for certain PDFs in my email. Then it generates a consolidated document thanks to the PDFApp library and saves it in My Google Drive.
Now I want another document to be generated from that Consolidated PDF document that will help me save paper for printing. And it involves taking the CONSOLIDATED document and printing it in PDF 2 pages per sheet. Thus, if the CONSOLIDATED document is 10 pages, in the new document it will only be 5 pages. I want to do that with Google App Script and I can't.
I think using https://pdf-lib.js.org/ I could do it, but I'm a newbie and I don't know how to use that library. Yes, I was able to use the PDFApp library because that library has the script id which I included in the Library and it worked, but https://pdf-lib.js.org/ I don't know how to use it. Or do you have any idea how I could do it?
I leave you the script that doesn't work for me to see if you can help me.
// Cargar PDF-LIB desde la URL
function loadPdfLib() {
  const url = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib@1.4.0/dist/pdf-lib.min.js';
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const jsCode = response.getContentText();
  eval(jsCode);
}

// Función principal para ejecutar el script
function generarAhorroPDF() {
  // Cargar PDF-LIB
  loadPdfLib();

  const folderName = 'RECIBOS DE PAGO';
  const subFolderName = 'RECIBO DE PAGO 2DA QUINCENA DE JUNIO 2024';
  const archivoNombre = 'CONSOLIDADO.pdf';
  const nuevoArchivoNombre = 'AHORRO.pdf';
  
  // Buscar la carpeta principal en Mi Unidad
  const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  if (!folders.hasNext()) {
    throw new Error('No se encontró la carpeta ' + folderName);
  }
  const folder = folders.next();
  
  // Buscar la subcarpeta en la carpeta principal
  const subFolders = folder.getFoldersByName(subFolderName);
  if (!subFolders.hasNext()) {
    throw new Error('No se encontró la subcarpeta ' + subFolderName);
  }
  const subFolder = subFolders.next();
  
  // Buscar el archivo PDF en la subcarpeta
  const files = subFolder.getFilesByName(archivoNombre);
  if (!files.hasNext()) {
    throw new Error('No se encontró el archivo ' + archivoNombre);
  }
  const file = files.next();
  
  // Obtener el contenido del archivo PDF
  const pdfBytes = file.getBlob().getBytes();
  
  // Cargar el documento PDF existente
  PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes).then(pdfDoc => {
    // Crear un nuevo documento PDF
    return PDFDocument.create().then(nuevoPdfDoc => {
      return pdfDoc.getPages().reduce((promise, pagina, index) => {
        return promise.then(() => {
          if (index % 2 === 0) {
            // Crear una nueva página en el nuevo documento
            const nuevaPagina = nuevoPdfDoc.addPage([595.276, 841.890]); // Tamaño de página A4 en puntos
            const { width, height } = nuevaPagina.getSize();
            
            // Dibuja la primera página en la mitad superior
            const { width: page1Width, height: page1Height } = pagina.getSize();
            nuevaPagina.drawPage(pagina, {
              x: 0,
              y: height / 2,
              width: page1Width * 0.5,
              height: page1Height * 0.5,
            });
            
            if (index + 1 < pdfDoc.getPageCount()) {
              // Dibuja la segunda página en la mitad inferior
              const pagina2 = pdfDoc.getPage(index + 1);
              const { width: page2Width, height: page2Height } = pagina2.getSize();
              nuevaPagina.drawPage(pagina2, {
                x: page1Width * 0.5,
                y: height / 2,
                width: page2Width * 0.5,
                height: page2Height * 0.5,
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
        // Guardar el nuevo archivo PDF
        return nuevoPdfDoc.save().then(nuevoPdfBytes => {
          const nuevoBlob = Utilities.newBlob(nuevoPdfBytes, 'application/pdf', nuevoArchivoNombre);
          
          // Subir el nuevo archivo PDF a la carpeta
          subFolder.createFile(nuevoBlob);
          Logger.log('Archivo ' + nuevoArchivoNombre + ' creado con éxito.');
        });
      });
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    Logger.log('Error al procesar el PDF: ' + error.message);
  });
}


I have tried many things, but I am not sure if I have done it right because I am not an expert.
